# How to open a mail then delete it from gmail using webdriver?

Tags: webdriver

How to read email and then delete the email from Gmail inbox

```
Browser.findElement("//*[@id=':5']/descendant::div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji nX T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-Gs  ar7'][2]").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

enter mail:

```
try {
            Maildriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div[2]/span")).click();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println(" Fail to find the mail and click it" ) ;
                }
```

click at "link" that can be found inside the mail  ( same you can do other stuff ).

```
                try {   
                WebElement approveByMailLink =   Maildriver.findElement(By.linkText("here")) ;
                approveByMailLink.click() ;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println(" Clicking the mail link (start your einstein account) failed" ) ;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\libs\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?");
UtilityMethods.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("YourID");//Email ID
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
UtilityMethods.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("YourPassword");//Password
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();//Sign IN
UtilityMethods.sleep(20000);
System.out.println("Mail Opened");
UtilityMethods.sleep(20000);
System.out.println("Delete all check box is displayed :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Select']")).isDisplayed()+"");
System.out.println("Delete all check box is Enabled   :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Select']")).isEnabled()+"");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Select']")).click();//Delete All Check BOX
UtilityMethods.sleep(20000);
System.out.println("Check box selected");
System.out.println("Delete button is displayed :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Delete']")).isDisplayed()+"");
System.out.println("Delete button is Enabled   :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Delete']")).isEnabled()+"");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Delete']")).click();//Delete BUtton
UtilityMethods.sleep(20000);
System.out.println("Delete Button Clicked");
```